# PHP curl empty result

Tags: php, curl

I have a php script that sends request to url. But result is empty.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip, deflate");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp',
    'Connection: Keep-Alive',
    'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'Format'=>'image/png',
    'width'=>'550',
    'height'=>'250',
));
$reuslt = curl_exec($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

I write `echo $reuslt;` but this gives error like this: **Notice: Undefined variable: result**

I write `echo $error;` this writes result 0

This query result should return a png image to my browser, but returs nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `$result` everywhere not `$reuslt` (or otherway, but not mixed)